# Error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, ForeignKey found?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add my model to my admin.py page, I've had to play around with my ManytoMany and Arrayfields fields to get it working correctly, however I'm not out of the mud yet.

Im getting this error: `Error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, ForeignKey found` when I try to add an object in my admin page.

Here is my original model:

```
class Bucket(models.Model):

    options = (
        ('personal', 'Personal'),
        ('social', 'Social'),
    )


    class BucketObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(Bucket.owner)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=options)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True) 
    stock_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True),size=30,null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    objects = models.Manager()
    bucketobjects = BucketObjects()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def total_stocks_calc(self):
        self.stock_count = Bucket.objects.aggregate(Sum('stock_list', distinct=True))
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bucket:bucket-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stock_list
```

here is my `admin.py` code:

```
@admin.register(models.Bucket)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = models.Bucket._meta.get_fields()
    list_display = ('id','owner','category', 'get_users', 'name', 'created',
                    'slug','stock_count','get_stocks', 'about')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',), }


    def get_users(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([u.users for u in obj.users.all()])
    
    def get_stocks(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([s.stock_list for s in obj.stock_list.all()])
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error.

EDIT: Full Traceback error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/bbucketmaster9/bucket/bucket/add/

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_filters',
 'users',
 'bucket',
 'bucket_api']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1568, in _changeform_view
    ModelForm = self.get_form(
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 709, in get_form
    return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 555, in modelform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 266, in __new__
    message = message % (', '.join(missing_fields),

Exception Type: TypeError at /bbucketmaster9/bucket/bucket/add/
Exception Value: sequence item 0: expected str instance, ForeignKey found
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? I assume the error is in the `get_users` and/or `get_stocks`?

Comment: Hey @WillemVanOnsem , I just updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make use of `models.Bucket._meta.get_fields()` for the fields. [**`get_fields(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields) will return a tuple of the *fields* itself, not the *name* of these fields.

```
@admin.register(models.Bucket)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = models.Bucket._meta.get_fields()
```

You can list the names of the fields explicitly, or with

```
@admin.register(models.Bucket)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [f.name for f in models.Bucket._meta.get_fields()]
```

But you actually do *not* need to specify the fields. As the [documentation on `fields` says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields):

> If neither `fields` nor `fieldsets` options are present, **Django will
> default to displaying each field that isn’t an `AutoField`** and has
> `editable=True`, in a single fieldset, in the same order as the fields
> are defined in the model.

Comment: Yes this solved the issue, thank you for your help!